# Subscription app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, subscription

I am currently developing a subscription app.
I currently have 6 View Controllers to which have different options on.
For example - Name - Amount - Date etc.

Once the user completes these, I want it to create a new view controller with this information on it.
So once they go back onto the main screen, they will be able to swipe left and it will show their subscription.

All I want to know is, is there a way I can create a new view controller with their information on it once they press a complete button on the Date page?
Transferring data to a view controller is the easy part. I am more wondering on how I can create a new view controller when they try and add another Subscription, if that makes sense.

If not is there a way I can do this?

Comment: You are having a problem "creating a new view controller" or "passing user data to a view controller"?

Comment: Its more creating a new view controller. I basically want it so, when they put data in Name - Amount - Date that will go to the view controller. But if they do it again, i want it to create another view controller. If that makes sense

Comment: Please refer [Link](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) you can implement

Comment: "how I can create a new view controller when they try and add another Subscription, if that makes sense" don't do it. If the user has 100 subscriptions, 100 view controllers wouldn't be too efficient. Instead, use just one viewController, and pass the information from the main screen to that VC every time you use it

Comment: I knew I shouldn't have all those controllers, was just seeing the best way I could do it without having loads of VC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options that I can think of. I am sure there are more, but these may help.

1. You could create a global instance of a struct that is your "subscription to add". You could then update the values for each property of this struct (e.g. name, amount, date, etc.) after each VC is dismissed
2. You can pass the data your user is generating to each VC through `prepareForSegue`. This is slightly redundant so I would recommend doing the first method. For the record, this segue method would look something like this:

VC 1 Dismissed: Pass Name to VC2

VC 2 Dismissed: Pass Name and Amount to VC3

VC 3 Dismissed: Pass Name, Amount, and Date to VC4 etc......

Once you have all of the information, you can show the last VC and just set the labels and such to the values of your struct, or the values you passed through the segue.

**Edit**: Further Information on Option 1

So if you made a struct like this:

```
struct UserToAdd {
    static var name: String = String()
    static var amount: Int = 0
    static var date: Date = Date()
}
```

with all of the properties that you want a subscription to have, then you can store this information in this struct as you progress through each VC.

For example, if your first VC got the subscription name, then when your "prepareForSegue" function is called, as you are about to move to the second VC, then you could do something like this:

```
UserToAdd.name = "My Subscription Name"
```

Of course the string you assign to this name would depend on the data the user enters and such, but I hope it illustrates my point. It would be a similar process for each initial VC, but then once you have all of the data you need, you could just then call this data when your last VC loads, and set it to the text of a label or something like this:

```
var nameLabel = UILabel()
nameLabel.text = UserToAdd.name
self.view.addSubview(nameLabel);
```

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you give me more detail on option 1 if you don't mind?

Comment: Okay thank you, I will give it ago and will get you know :)

Comment: You can put the struct wherever you want, it just can't be in a class so that you can reach it in every VC.

Comment: Okay so I have done this and now I have the name on my mainVC. How can I input multiple Names so when the user swipes left on MainVC they will see their subscriptions. For example They input Netflix on NameVC, Then once the go to MainVC they Swipe left and see their Netflix Subscription. and other subscriptions they have made? if that makes sense

Comment: Well see you would eventually have an array of the subscriptions that you have. When you add a new subscription, it gets appended to that list. When you want the user to see all of their subscriptions, then you just iterate through the array and get the information.

Comment: @GeorgeCopeland If this answer helped you solve you problem, don't forget to upvote it / mark it as accepted so that users can benefit from it in the future. Thanks :)

Comment: I will do. Just a bit stuck on showing the array. Because I have it all working but everything they save is going into the same textfield. If that makes sense.

Comment: So by all the i mean how can i go through the array with a left swipe?

Comment: @GeorgeCopeland I think you're really starting to encounter a different problem. Generally on SO we ask specific questions, and then if there are follow ups, you create a post for a new question. I may be able to help you again, but this discussion is becoming less and less relevant to your current post. Thanks!